# Indexing business hours using google app engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, indexing, hash, bigtable

Given a time range in a day (business open hours) how could you create an index that would return a entity given the current time.

I made the mistake of assuming a list property containing just the open and close hours could work on app engine.  The following fails because the two inequality filters must match the same value in the list:

```
Select * FROM Business WHERE hours < now AND hours > now
```

Now I'm somewhat invested and without a solution aside from using a long list of times, sliced  every 30 minutes which seems very inefficient:

```
[900, 930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130, 1200, 1230, 1300, 1330, 1400, 1430, ... ]
```

Anyone know of a clever way of hashing open and close times or otherwise solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**NEW ANSWER:**
I thought about it a bit, I think you actually have the solution in your original idea.  For each business, have a storehours ListProperty that only stores times when the business is open, like you currently do.  Then calculate the current time, and round it to the nearest half hour, so 12:50 -> 1200, then do a query

```
now = 1200
Select * FROM Business WHERE now in hours
```

I'm not certain about the proper GQL query syntax, but there's definitely an "in" filter.

**OLD ANSWER (Do not read)**:
I'm doing something similar, I don't really have a solution, except for "try something different".

Firstly, you need to store both the open and close times.  Either as two separate fields, or encode them into one field, like '09001700' for 9-5, or even 'M09001700'.  Or hash the two into a number, I don't think this makes a huge difference, whichever way you do it.

Then the bad news.  I'm not particularly great at number theory, but what we're trying to do here is encode two linear sets of numbers (open and close times) in such a way that you can do a linear > or < comparison on a third number that represents 'now'.  I don't think this is possible, you can only get a successful > or < comparison on one of the two numbers, either open or close times.  So given that we can only do an inequality on one property, I don't think it's possible to have a single query isolate only the open stores.

I also don't think you need to do two queries, you only need to do one query on say the open hours, and then filter through them to see which ones are closed.  If you

You don't necessarily need to AND two big sets together.  You could query on all items where now > opentime, and manually filter through the results looking for items where now < closetime.  If you sort the query based on closetime, this should make the filtering somewhat easier.

The solution that I eventually went with, which might work for you, is to not query on store hours at all, but query on something that will return a more limited dataset, and then filter the returned results based on store hours.  For example, if your users search by location, query your businesses based on the location, and filter the resulting business by store hours, then only display the open ones to the user.

Comment: I actually went the route of using an Expando model and create dynamic boolean properties representing each day of the week and corresponding open times rounded to the nearest 15 minutes (Yes, lots' of boolean properties per model). This worked for one day of the week but exceed the 200 index quota for all days.

The problem with the list method, is you're limited to 30 elements in a list 'cause the values are basically OR'd together as separate queries on the back end.

I'm actually stumped right now and would love to discuss solutions in more details.

Comment: Where are you getting the 30 elements limit from?  The limit's at 5000 indexed properties per entity, and each element in the list would count as one.

You might have complications if you're searching for a range ([900,930,1000] IN hours), but searching for 1 time in the list should be fine (930 in hours).

Comment: Ah, I mistook the docs regarding IN filters on lists which are limited to 30, to this situation which is actually the other way around. [link] (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html#Lists)

Answer (score 0):

One of doing this would be to set an opentime and a closetime for each business and seeing if the hour of day is in between.

However with big table you may have to do two separate queries due to indexing. One query to see if the time is greater than opentime and another to see if it is less than closetime. This would be two indexes.

Not an ideal solution but it may be more efficient than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yea, big table also has the restriction of only allowing inequalities on one property, hense my attempt to use a list.  

If I have maybe 9000 records I need to query, in your two query solution then I'll have two fairly large querysets returned that I have to AND after the fact.  This is actually multiplied because a business can actually have multiple open and close pairs in a day.